# Role based Authentication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image] 
I'm developing an app with flutter. he app should use different pages for different kinds of users. There are 4 kinds of user: "Admin", "Staff", "Member", "Collector". The problem is, that I'm not able to get to the different pages and always stay on SiginPage. I'm new on this flutter and dart so I need someone to help me for my capstone project. Thank you!

Here's my code for main.dart

```
import 'package:capstone_project/account/admin_page.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/account/collector_page.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/account/member_page.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/account/staff_page.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/signinsignuppage/signin_page.dart';
import 'package:capstone_project/signinsignuppage/utils.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: messengerKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


   Future<String> getRole(String uid) async {
    String role = 'member';

    try {
      final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(uid)
          .get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        role = snapshot.get('role').toString();
        
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist in the database');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return role;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Something Went Wrong!'));
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // User is authenticated, check their role
            final user = snapshot.data!;
            return FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: getRole(user.uid),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(child: Text('Something Went Wrong!'));
                } else {
                  final String? role = snapshot.data;
                  if (role == "admin") {
                    return const AdminPage();
                  } else if (role == "staff") {
                    return const StaffPage();
                  } else if (role == "member") {
                    return const MemberPage();
                  } else if (role == "collector") {
                    return const CollectorPage();
                  } else {
                    // Unknown role, handle accordingly
                    return const SigninPage();
                  }
                }
              },
            );
          } else {
            // User is not authenticated, show sign-in page
            return const SigninPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Here's my code in sign up:

```
    Future signUp() async{
      final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
      if (!isValid) return;
    
    
        showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, 
        builder: (context) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
    
        try{
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text.trim(),
          password: passwordController.text.trim(),
        );
    
        //Display User to FireStore
        addUserDetailes(
          firstnameController.text.trim(),
          middlenameController.text.trim(),
          lastnameController.text.trim(),
          fulladdressController.text.trim(),
          civilstatuscontroller.text.trim(),
          emailController.text.trim(),
          int.parse(phonenoController.text.trim()),
          int.parse(ageController.text.trim()),
          );
        }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){
          print(e);
    
          Utils.showSnackBar(e.message);
        }
    
        //Navigator.of(context) not working! 
        navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) =>route.isFirst);
      }
    
    //display to database
    Future addUserDetailes(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String fullAddress, String civilStatus, String email, int phoneNumber, int age ) async{
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
        'first name': firstName,
        'middle name': middleName,
        'last name': lastName,
        'full address': fullAddress,
        'civil status' : civilStatus,
        'email': email,
        'phone number': phoneNumber,
        'age' : age,
        
      });
    }
```

Here my code for getRole:

```
Future<String> getRole(String id) async {
    String role = "member";
    try {
      final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(FireStoreConstants.users)
          .doc(id)
          .get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${snapshot.data()}');
        role = snapshot.get("role").toString();
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist in the database');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return role;
  }
}

class FireStoreConstants {
  static const String users = 'users';
}
```

But the code still directing to `return const SigninPage();`

Comment: please add your code to the the question not an image

Comment: Sorry, I already add it.

Comment: where is your getUserRole() ?

Comment: enum UserRole {
  admin,
  staff,
  member,
  collector,
}

Comment: getUserRole(String uid) {
}

Comment: no i mean function   future: getUserRole(users.uid), this add it to the question

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the idea on what should be the conditions am I going to code inside. So can you please elaborate the conditions to get my code right?

Comment: Future<String> getUserRole(String userId) async {
  final userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get();
  final role = userDoc.data()?['role'] as String;
  return role;
}

Answer (score 0):

In your getRole function, you need to use like this, this is returning String so you maybe need to check the UserRole type is equal to String, if the role didn't get successfully this will return the member

```
Future<String> getRole(String id) async {
String role = "member";
try {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(FireStoreConstants.pathUserCollection)//add your collection name
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
      role = await documentSnapshot.get("role");
    } else {
      print('Document does not exist on the database');
    }
  });
} catch(e){
  print(e);
}
return role;
```

}

after that In your future builder, you are not getting the UserRole you are getting the String change the model to String,

```
final String role= snapshot.data;
if(role=="admin"){
//your logic}
else if(role=="member"){
//your logic }
```

Comment: Where do I put the code?

Comment: before this Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold( then change your function    future: getUserRole(users.uid), to  future: getRole(users.uid)

Comment: how do I add the rest roles?

Comment: what do you mean by that, you can get your roles in this ,if the user isnt defined in firestore db this will return the member //you can change this to whatever you need ,if the role is assigned then you will get that  role

Comment: Sorry, I can't still fix the problem

Comment: If I log in the code will direct to one page

Comment: In your future builder, you are not getting the UserRole you are getting the String change the model to String ,final String role= snapshot.data;

Comment: I just try it and still has error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I just uploaded my main.dart

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It has no error, but the code doesn't go to the right pages when I log in as admin or member.

Comment: when I put String role ="admin" he will go there, just like directing

Comment: print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}'); what is this line print ? (in console)

Comment: I already updated my main.dart

Comment: The problem here in my main.dart, in this code String role = 'members'; what you put is the page that will appear. only the member page will appear the rest it will not log in and stay on sign in page.

Comment: maybe the user ID is the problem or my firebase firestore?

Comment: just manually check the user id, Use firestore id and add that id to getRole("askcjaskjcbsa")//id like this ,( firestore document id arent using the same id if you didnt specifiy it when creating the documnet)

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry if I have so many questions. I'm new to this flutter and firebase

Comment: copy your doc id in firestore then add it to the getRole("oXcsacscasc")//id

Comment: Then what next? 
(CDa7k15BYtqPiNSSfS9q) this is the ID for member

Comment: run that gain and see the results

Comment: It will direct to the page of member

Answer (score 0):

In your build function replace your `return FutureBuilder<UserRole>` with return `FutureBuilder<String>` 
If this doesn't solves your issue, then in your build function do `print(snapshot.data);` for debugging.

Comment: I already did it, but still has error

Comment: maybe the problem is with firestore firebase?

Comment: Your app is working fine on my setup. Could you please post your log after you click sign in? Also I couldn't find SignInPage() in your post which is very much needed. Also does this issue only occurs in Sign In or  Sign Up or it occurs in both?

Comment: Also make sure your navigatorKey and messengerKey are same and unique across the entire app. See that you are not creating more than one instances and make sure to use the same instance everywhere in the app.